# Как заставить работать данный код со всеми input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как заставить работать данный код со всеми input?

```js
const InputFormatType = {
    THOUSAND: 3
};
const decorator = ( value, format = InputFormatType.THOUSAND ) => value
    .split( '' )
    .filter( char => char !== " " )
    .reverse()
    .reduce( ( result, char, index ) => result += (( index >= format && index % format === 0 ? " " : "" ) + char), "" )
    .split( '' )
    .reverse()
    .join( '' );

const input = document.body.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', input_inputHandler);

function input_inputHandler( { target } ){
  target.value = decorator( target.value );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const InputFormatType = {
    THOUSAND: 3
};
const decorator = ( value, format = InputFormatType.THOUSAND ) => value
    .split( '' )
    .filter( char => char !== " " )
    .reverse()
    .reduce( ( result, char, index ) => result += (( index >= format && index % format === 0 ? " " : "" ) + char), "" )
    .split( '' )
    .reverse()
    .join( '' );

// Выбираем все элементы селектора
const inputs = document.body.querySelectorAll('input');

// Перебираем элементы, навешивая на каждый обработчик события
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('input', input_inputHandler);
});

function input_inputHandler( { target } ){
  target.value = decorator( target.value );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
```

Comment: Благодарю за доступное объяснение)